# How to make div resizeable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag

```
$().ready(function () {
    $(".MySplitter").splitter();
 });

 /*
  * jQuery.splitter.js - two-pane splitter window plugin
  *
  * version 1.51 (2009/01/09) 
  * 
  * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses: 
  *   https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php 
  *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html 
  */

 /**
  * The splitter() plugin implements a two-pane resizable splitter window.
  * The selected elements in the jQuery object are converted to a splitter;
  * each selected element should have two child elements, used for the panes
  * of the splitter. The plugin adds a third child element for the splitbar.
  * 
  * For more details see: http://methvin.com/splitter/
  *
  *
  * @example $('#MySplitter').splitter();
  * @desc Create a vertical splitter with default settings 
  *
  * @example $('#MySplitter').splitter({type: 'h', accessKey: 'M'});
  * @desc Create a horizontal splitter resizable via Alt+Shift+M
  *
  * @name splitter
  * @type jQuery
  * @param Object options Options for the splitter (not required)
  * @cat Plugins/Splitter
  * @return jQuery
  * @author Dave Methvin (dave.methvin@gmail.com)
  */
 ; (function ($) {

     $.fn.splitter = function (args) {
         args = args || {};

         return this.each(function () {
             var zombie;     // left-behind splitbar for outline resizes

             function getEventPosition(evt) {
                 return evt.originalEvent.touches && evt.originalEvent.touches.length ? evt.originalEvent.touches[0][opts.eventPos] : evt[opts.eventPos];
             }

             function startSplitMouse(evt) {
                 if (opts.outline)
                     zombie = zombie || bar.clone(false).insertAfter(A);
                 panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "none");   // Safari selects A/B text on a move
                 bar.addClass(opts.activeClass);
                 A._posSplit = A[0][opts.pxSplit] - getEventPosition(evt);
                 $(document)
                     .bind("mousemove touchmove", doSplitMouse)
                     .bind("mouseup touchend", endSplitMouse);
             }
             function doSplitMouse(evt) {
                 var newPos = A._posSplit + getEventPosition(evt);
                 if (opts.outline) {
                     newPos = Math.max(0, Math.min(newPos, splitter._DA - bar._DA));
                     bar.css(opts.origin, newPos);
                 } else
                     resplit(newPos);
             }
             function endSplitMouse(evt) {
                 bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass);
                 var newPos = A._posSplit + getEventPosition(evt);
                 if (opts.outline) {
                     zombie.remove(); zombie = null;
                     resplit(newPos);
                 }
                 panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "text");   // let Safari select text again
                 $(document)
                     .unbind("mousemove touchmove", doSplitMouse)
                     .unbind("mouseup touchend", endSplitMouse);
             }
             function resplit(newPos) {
                 // Constrain new splitbar position to fit pane size limits
                 newPos = Math.max(A._min, splitter._DA - B._max,
                         Math.min(newPos, A._max, splitter._DA - bar._DA - B._min));
                 // Resize/position the two panes
                 bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];     // bar size may change during dock
                 bar.css(opts.origin, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                 A.css(opts.origin, 0).css(opts.split, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                 B.css(opts.origin, newPos + bar._DA)
                     .css(opts.split, splitter._DA - bar._DA - newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
                 // IE fires resize for us; all others pay cash
                 if (!$.browser.msie)
                     panes.trigger("resize");
             }
             function dimSum(jq, dims) {
                 // Opera returns -1 for missing min/max width, turn into 0
                 var sum = 0;
                 for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
                     sum += Math.max(parseInt(jq.css(arguments[i])) || 0, 0);
                 return sum;
             }

             // Determine settings based on incoming opts, element classes, and defaults
             var vh = (args.splitHorizontal ? 'h' : args.splitVertical ? 'v' : args.type) || 'v';
             var opts = $.extend({
                 activeClass: 'active',  // class name for active splitter
                 pxPerKey: 8,            // splitter px moved per keypress
                 tabIndex: 0,            // tab order indicator
                 accessKey: ''           // accessKey for splitbar
             }, {
                 v: {                    // Vertical splitters:
                     keyLeft: 39, keyRight: 37, cursor: "grabbing",
                     splitbarClass: "vsplitbar", outlineClass: "voutline",
                     type: 'v', eventPos: "pageX", origin: "left",
                     split: "width", pxSplit: "offsetWidth", side1: "Left", side2: "Right",
                     fixed: "height", pxFixed: "offsetHeight", side3: "Top", side4: "Bottom"
                 },
                 h: {                    // Horizontal splitters:
                     keyTop: 40, keyBottom: 38, cursor: "n-resize",
                     splitbarClass: "hsplitbar", outlineClass: "houtline",
                     type: 'h', eventPos: "pageY", origin: "top",
                     split: "height", pxSplit: "offsetHeight", side1: "Top", side2: "Bottom",
                     fixed: "width", pxFixed: "offsetWidth", side3: "Left", side4: "Right"
                 }
             }[vh], args);

             // Create jQuery object closures for splitter and both panes
             var splitter = $(this).css({ position: "relative" });
             var panes = $(">*", splitter[0]).css({
                 position: "absolute",           // positioned inside splitter container
                 "z-index": "1",                 // splitbar is positioned above
                 "-moz-outline-style": "none"    // don't show dotted outline
             });
             var A = $(panes[0]);        // left  or top
             var B = $(panes[1]);        // right or bottom

             // Focuser element, provides keyboard support; title is shown by Opera accessKeys
             $.extend({
                   browser : {
                       opera : /opera/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())
                 }
             }) 
             //$.browser.mozilla = /firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
             //$.browser.webkit = /webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

             //$.browser.msie = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
             var focuser = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>')
                 .attr({ accessKey: opts.accessKey, tabIndex: opts.tabIndex, title: opts.splitbarClass })
                 .bind($.browser.opera ? "click" : "focus", function () { this.focus(); bar.addClass(opts.activeClass) })
                 .bind("keydown", function (e) {
                     var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
                     var dir = key == opts["key" + opts.side1] ? 1 : key == opts["key" + opts.side2] ? -1 : 0;
                     if (dir)
                         resplit(A[0][opts.pxSplit] + dir * opts.pxPerKey, false);
                 })
                 .bind("blur", function () { bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass) });

             // Splitbar element, can be already in the doc or we create one
             var bar = $(panes[2] || '<div></div>')
                 .insertAfter(A).css("z-index", "100").append(focuser)
                 .attr({ "class": opts.splitbarClass, unselectable: "on" })
                 .css({
                     position: "absolute", "user-select": "none", "-webkit-user-select": "none",
                     "-khtml-user-select": "none", "-moz-user-select": "none"
                 })
                 .bind("mousedown touchstart", startSplitMouse);
             // Use our cursor unless the style specifies a non-default cursor
             if (/^(auto|default|)$/.test(bar.css("cursor")))
                 bar.css("cursor", opts.cursor);

             // Cache several dimensions for speed, rather than re-querying constantly
             bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];
             splitter._PBF = $.boxModel ? dimSum(splitter, "border" + opts.side3 + "Width", "border" + opts.side4 + "Width") : 0;
             splitter._PBA = $.boxModel ? dimSum(splitter, "border" + opts.side1 + "Width", "border" + opts.side2 + "Width") : 0;
             A._pane = opts.side1;
             B._pane = opts.side2;
             $.each([A, B], function () {
                 this._min = opts["min" + this._pane] || dimSum(this, "min-" + opts.split);
                 this._max = opts["max" + this._pane] || dimSum(this, "max-" + opts.split) || 9999;
                 this._init = opts["size" + this._pane] === true ?
                     parseInt($.curCSS(this[0], opts.split)) : opts["size" + this._pane];
             });

             // Determine initial position, get from cookie if specified
             var initPos = A._init;
             if (!isNaN(B._init))    // recalc initial B size as an offset from the top or left side
                 initPos = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - B._init - bar._DA;
             if (opts.cookie) {
                 if (!$.cookie)
                     alert('jQuery.splitter(): jQuery cookie plugin required');
                 var ckpos = parseInt($.cookie(opts.cookie));
                 if (!isNaN(ckpos))
                     initPos = ckpos;
                 $(window).bind("unload", function () {
                     var state = String(bar.css(opts.origin));   // current location of splitbar
                     $.cookie(opts.cookie, state, {
                         expires: opts.cookieExpires || 365,
                         path: opts.cookiePath || document.location.pathname
                     });
                 });
             }
             if (isNaN(initPos)) // King Solomon's algorithm
                 initPos = Math.round((splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - bar._DA) / 2);

             // Resize event propagation and splitter sizing
             if (opts.anchorToWindow) {
                 // Account for margin or border on the splitter container and enforce min height
                 splitter._hadjust = dimSum(splitter, "borderTopWidth", "borderBottomWidth", "marginBottom");
                 splitter._hmin = Math.max(dimSum(splitter, "minHeight"), 20);
                 $(window).bind("resize", function () {
                     var top = splitter.offset().top;
                     var wh = $(window).height();
                     splitter.css("height", Math.max(wh - top - splitter._hadjust, splitter._hmin) + "px");
                     if (!$.browser.msie) splitter.trigger("resize");
                 }).trigger("resize");
             }
             else if (opts.resizeToWidth && !$.browser.msie)
                 $(window).bind("resize", function () {
                     splitter.trigger("resize");
                 });

             // Resize event handler; triggered immediately to set initial position
             splitter.bind("resize", function (e, size) {
                 // Custom events bubble in jQuery 1.3; don't get into a Yo Dawg
                 if (e.target != this) return;
                 // Determine new width/height of splitter container
                 splitter._DF = splitter[0][opts.pxFixed] - splitter._PBF;
                 splitter._DA = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA;
                 // Bail if splitter isn't visible or content isn't there yet
                 if (splitter._DF <= 0 || splitter._DA <= 0) return;
                 // Re-divvy the adjustable dimension; maintain size of the preferred pane
                 resplit(!isNaN(size) ? size : (!(opts.sizeRight || opts.sizeBottom) ? A[0][opts.pxSplit] :
                     splitter._DA - B[0][opts.pxSplit] - bar._DA));
             }).trigger("resize", [initPos]);
         });
     };

 })(jQuery);
```

Hey guys I have created a section for my project. But the client need more customization on that. And before reading my needs please open the link that I given below.

http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/nb-interactions/test-one/

In this link you can drag that boarder placed in the center, then you can see the full size image of left or right. Here I given those images as two parts. But my client says they need to show them as a one image with two effects. Suppose half of one image has to be in black and white and other side has to be in color. Also we need to use two different images there. 
So can you help me with that?

I have attached my javascript code above, please go through that and plase help me. Thanks :)

This image will give you more clarification.
[image]

Comment: Seems like your question is too broad pal, try to reduce it and be more specific, so you get some real help here.

Comment: Hey skobaljic, It's kind of complicated that's why i described this way :)

Comment: Your question is a little broad as previously mentioned but i think the effect you are looking for is something along these lines : https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/wtCoa

Comment: You cannot achieve it only by CSS you need scss and jquery working together. I got a working solution for you, using existing twentytwenty.js you can achieve it easily and customize CSS as you like. You need to put two images for the effect to work.  [Working example](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/LgvGrv).

Comment: Hey  Aaron McGuire and Mohammed Wahed Khan, thanks for the answers. It was the thing i'm actually looking for. But the problem is "https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/LgvGrv" this example is not working in internet explorer, is there any way to help with that?. And "https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/wtCoa" in this example they are placing one image using style. Can we avoid that?

Comment: Actually I need to put both images as <img> can we do that?

Comment: Not sure if im missing something here but cant you just hide the border? Then it would look like one image with two effects

Comment: On the link you've provided, if you make the div with the class' `grid right` 180px from the left it gets rid of the gap

Comment: Try this, this is by using basic jquery and jqueryui [Working in IE](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/mzgEJx)